# Can I import a global variable from a DLL ? Can I do this with a DEF file?

Tags: c, visual-c++, dll, dllimport, dllexport

gcc has no problem with this, but I struggle to achieve the same thing with link.exe (visualc)

in dll.c, I define

```
int myint = 0 ;
int myfunc ( .... ) {  ...  } ;
```

in dll.h

```
extern int myint ;
int myfunc ( .... ) ;
```

in dll.def

```
LIBRARY mydll
EXPORTS
    myint
    myfunc
```

Everything works fine, the dll is created, I can link with it, my executable calls myfunc() successfully.
But I don't know how to tell the linker that myint is a variable and not a function. So when I try

```
myint = 1 ;
```

the application crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember well, with c++ you need to explicitly import global variable (it's implicit with function). I'd try with `__declspec( dllimport ) int  myint;`

If you want to compile for windows and you are already developing under linux with GCC, I'd cross-compile from linux with mingw, it's a lot easier in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, it works (I've even added DATA in the DEF file as recommended by microsoft). I would prefer a method that doesn't oblige me to deal with __declspec( dllimport/dllexport ), but it is better than nothing. Until now, I was doing it with mingw-gcc, but with mingwin, the window's includes/libraries are not as good/recent as the visualc ones, and I end up opening old style dialogs instead of the latest kind.

Comment: I know what you mean, about the whole __declspec thing. It's easier though when you share your code for others to understand where the variables come from.
For mingw, I include myself the most recent lib, it's more work but so much easier when you compile.