# Import of global variable failed C++

Tags: c++, dll, global

I have dll with a code:

Dll.h:

```
#ifndef EXPORT
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif
#ifndef IMPORT
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#include <iostream>
#ifndef MY_GLOBALS_H
#define MY_GLOBALS_H
        
EXPORT extern int test;
        
EXPORT void pritnTestHpp() {
std::cout << "HPP:" << test << " Pointer=" << (unsigned)(&test) << std::endl;
}
EXPORT void pritnTestCpp();
#endif
```

Dll.cpp:

```
#include "Dll.h"
EXPORT int test = 0;

void pritnTestCpp() {
    std::cout << "CPP:" << test << " Pointer=" << (unsigned)(&test) << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Dll.h"

__declspec(dllimport) int test;

int main()
{
    test = 4;
    pritnTestHpp();
    pritnTestCpp();
    std::cout << "GUI:" << test << " Pointer=" << (unsigned)(&test) << std::endl;
}
```

Receiving output:

HPP:4 Pointer=3092644928

CPP:0 Pointer=3991531888

GUI:4 Pointer=3092644928

I wonder, why in .cpp is another pointer. Linking in Visual Studio works and I am not aware of any mistake.

I guided myself by memory and searched also in:
[Can I import a global variable from a DLL ? Can I do this with a DEF file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248611/can-i-import-a-global-variable-from-a-dll-can-i-do-this-with-a-def-file)
[Exporting global variables from DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3097548/exporting-global-variables-from-dll)

It seems identical but for me it does not works. Can you tell me plese, why?

Comment: `EXPORT` for inline function is suspicious. Unconditional EXPORT is suspicious too.

Comment: I think `__declspec(dllimport) int test;` should be `__declspec(dllimport) extern int test;`. Plus you should **either** export **or** import (depending on whether you are compiling the DLL or the program) not both at the same time, like you are doing.

Comment: @john This throws unresolved externals in main.

Comment: ***This throws unresolved externals in main.*** it will if you fail to link to the import library generated with the dll.

Comment: You may want to go back start over with this Microsoft tutorial: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: @john `__declspec(dllimport) int test;` should be completely removed from `Main.cpp` and the declaration in `Dll.h` should be fixed.

Comment: Global variables on its own are bad, but combined with dll's just asking for trouble. See if you can make a design that does not depend on global variables

Comment: I thought that this is easy problem. I wonder that nobody knows how to solve this "basic" problem? Nobody of C/C++ programers use global variables? Sorry guys, but I don't ask what I should not do it, I ask what I should do to make code work and learn that way more about how compiling and linking works... Don't need general tutorial links, need explicit answer, this is why I am here...

Comment: @Ales100 If you have unresolved references it's because you are failing to link with the import library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not difficult, you just have to know what you are doing. That's why it's recommended to read the boring general tutorials.

Anyway here is some working code, followed by some important build notes.

dll.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef DLL
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <iostream>

EXPORT extern int test;

inline void printTestHpp() {
    std::cout << "HPP:" << test << " Pointer=" << &test << std::endl;
}

EXPORT void printTestCpp();
```

dll.cpp

```
#include "Dll.h"

int test = 0;

void printTestCpp() {
    std::cout << "CPP:" << test << " Pointer=" << &test << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "dll.h"

int main()
{
    test = 4;
    printTestHpp();
    printTestCpp();
    std::cout << "GUI:" << test << " Pointer=" << &test << std::endl;
}
```

Output

```
HPP:4 Pointer=00007FFB6AB2D170
CPP:4 Pointer=00007FFB6AB2D170
GUI:4 Pointer=00007FFB6AB2D170
```

Now the important build notes are that the preprocessor symbol `DLL` must be defined when building the DLL, and not be defined when building the main program. It's this trick that you seem to be missing in your attempts. Secondly, building the DLL will result in the creation of an import library (called something like dll.lib). You must link this import library with your main program, otherwise you will get unresolved symbols.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, John! This is exactly what I needed.